# AWS Lambda - Event object is empty even though "Use Lambda Proxy integration" is enabled

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I use a lambda function via the API gateway. It works great but the event object is empty.
Googling it says that I have to enable "**Use Lambda Proxy integration**" in API gateway. It is still empty and I cannot find why it happens.

```
def foo(event, context):
    return {
        "success": True,
        "event": event
    }
```

Returns

```
{"success": true, "event": {}}
```

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow could you post a screenshot of your integration request screen please? So go into APIG, go into the endpoint, click method(IE GET) on the right, click integration request

Comment: @MrkFldig here you go: https://ibb.co/3rQhYT5

Comment: Hold up, how are you invoking this endpoint via the Lambda console or via something like postman?

Comment: Basically if you're doing it via the Lambda console it won't have an event object, you need to go APIG, click your api, click stages, click your stage, they'll be an INVOKE URL you need to use that ie blahblah.blahablah.blahblah/scan using whatever method it's setup for(IE GET/POST etc etc) use postman for windows or PAW for MacOs.

Comment: @MrkFldig this is exactly what I am doing - the object is still empty. :( I want to be able to pass query params to it but without the event object it is impossible...

Comment: Ahh wait have you redeployed your API? When you make changes go to your Resources, click the button that says actions and then deploy?

Comment: Comment corrected it's resources not stage.

Comment: @MrkFldig, yes I redeployed it - does not help :(

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?